# How to create an individual account for an existing household account?

Tags: account, contact, accountcontactrelation, health-cloud

How can I add an individual account to an existing Household Account?

I tried to create an individual Account + Contact and link them together (Household>Contact>Individual) but I am stopped by the message **"Can't choose a person as the account in this relationship."**

What is the proper way to add a new person to a Household?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.add_household_members.htm&type=5)?

Comment: It looks like I don't have the option to "Add Member"